# Drain and vent the toilet from waste line? (Wet vent)

Tags: plumbing, toilet

I have a plumbing question and hope that someone with plumbing knowledge will lend a hand.

Can I connect my toilet drain line where the red circle is drawn to my second toilet?  The T fitting just before the red outline is connected to a toilet to the left and a vent stack above.  My question is if my toilet is less than 4’ away from this vent stack, and I’m using 3” ABS, can I tie my wasteline from the second toilet directly into the wasteline downstream from the stack and still achieve proper ventilation?  I also, is this acceptable per code in CA?

Thanks a ton!

[image]

Comment: Within 5 of the vent you should be ok.

Comment: The wood looks old but the concrete footings looks quite new, was the foundation rebuilt on this house or am I seeing things?

Comment: No foundation work has been done.  The plumbing question is the one I’m looking for an answer to.  Can I wet vent the 2nd toilet where the red circle is drawn?